# CalendarStyle of DatePicker different than my custom CalendarStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, calendar, styles

I have a custom Calendar style and a custom DatePicker style.

***Code in my MyCustomSkin.xaml (from my library project)***

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

They are both inside my MyCustomSkin.xaml ResourceDictionary (separate solution that generate a MyCustomSkin.dll) that I reference inside my application.

***Code in my App.xaml (from my application)***

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCustomSkin;component/MyCustomSkin.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

***Code in my MainWindow.xaml (from my application)***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Calendar HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I create a Calendar in my application (without specifying any style), the background is red.
When I am creating a DatePicker in my application (without specifying any style), the background is green but the background of its calendar is the system one (=> not red).

Why? I thougt that I was overriding all the system calendars with mine. Why is it applying the custom style for the Calendar but not on the Calendar of DatePicker?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your MyCustomSkin.xaml should be:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePicker}" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="CalendarStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Calendar}}"/>

                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

DatePicker has a default CalendarStyle which will be applied on component initialization.

Comment: I have my styles in a separate solution (a .dll). I do not want to give a x:key as I want to all my calendars to have the style I defined. I do not want to specify in my application the styles of the calendar. I want my application to automatically use the defined styles. And it is working as I am getting the calendar with the red background by just have <Calendar/> in my code.
I just edited my question with more details.

Comment: With your (new) solution, I will need to duplicate my code (have my calendar style for "normal" calendar AND a local calendar style for the DatePicker). It's something that I do not want to do but I have no idea if it is possible actually.

Comment: Do I have no other choices than "Duplicate a local calendar style in my DatePicker" or "Give a x:key to my Calendar style" ?

Comment: If you want to avoid code duplication set DatePicker CalendarStyle base to application calendar style. Edited my answer with basedOn style

Comment: I did a try, it is still the default system style :(